# Can you eat red tomatoes' seeds that turned black?

Tags: tomatoes

I bought bright red tomatoes from a supermarket that looked fresh, ripe, edible on the outside. I descry no evidence of Blossom End Rot; the tomatoes isn't blemished like pics below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I cut open the tomato, the flesh remains red and feels normal and fresh. But most seeds are black, rather than [Goldenrod Yellow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shades_of_yellow#/media/File:Goldenrods_in_Fountain_County,_Indiana.png).

1. Why did these seeds turn black?
2. What, if anything, can be safely eaten? Just the flesh? Or even the seeds?

I forgot to photo-graph, but please edit this if anyone finds a picture of this snag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like BER (blossom-end rot) which can occur with only the seeds being affected if the condition wasn't severe enough (or for enough time) to affect the flesh. If you remove the seeds (and any parts of the flesh the may have been affected) the rest is safe to eat.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if tomatoes have been picked unripe (e.g. for supermarket distribution), they may go from hard to rotten without going through ripe! The black seeds are a sign of ageing. It can happen on nice local tomates too but the flesh will go quite soft first. As myklbykl suggests, just get rid of the seeds. No problem if you are going to cube them for a salsa but not great in a tomato salad...